# R datetime scaling

Tags: r, date, datetime

My dataset df has datetime column,
this column's format is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM`

I made new column that has only `YYYY-MM-DD` using

```
df$date <- factor(as.Date(df$datetime))
```

but I can't make column that has only time,
I want to make new column 'time' that has format `HH:MM`

Comment: Look at the  "chron" package, there should be a function available for this.  In general, base R requires a time to be associated with a date to be valid.

Comment: Honestly, it's almost certainly a better idea to keep it as a datetime class; it's considerably easier to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `strptime` and `strftime`, the former convert character vectors to `POSIXct` and `POSIXlt` class( or date time class) and the latter does the opposite. With the `format` parameter, you can easily convert and format your datetime:

```
s = "2016-01-01 10:20"

strftime(strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), "%H:%M")
# [1] "10:20"

strftime(strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), "%Y-%M-%d")
# [1] "2016-20-01"
```